# How to use group by in codeigniter to count some value?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

How can i use group by for following case:

I have a table called **Sitekey** in here i have list of License keys.

[image: Sitekey Table]

The **Site_Key field** contains the license keys for my product.
The **Org_id** contains the id of the organization to which that key has been assigned.

Now I have another table called **activation**.
Its Structure is:

[image: activation table]

Now in this table Site_key contains the license(key). and the device information.

Now I want to show licenses available in table to whom they are assigned.

I do this :

```
public function get_key()
{

    $this->db->select('*');  
    $this->db->from('sitekey');
    $this->db->join('company', 'sitekey.org_id = company.id');
    $this->db->order_by('sitekey.id','desc');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result   = $query->result();              
    return $result;

}
```

> Now I want get the count of keys that are used in activation table!
>   **> in sitekey table  the licenses field contains the number of licenses so the company can use that key for that number of times. Now i want to get the key i gave them and the keys they have used from it.**
>   So i guess i need to use group by So how can i write such a query ?

**Note**

I want to count the keys in activation table. For eg there is a key :**`4CAC-9CA7`** Then i want to know how many times it has been used ? So i want to count all this for all keys

The Company Table:

[image: company table]

Comment: have you tried `$this->db->group_by("columnName"); `??

Comment: @AjayMakwana i saw that in user_guide. but i dont know how to use it here! what should be my query here

Comment: @MathBio i did not understant u please explain me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function get_key() 
{ 

$this->db->select('company.org_name, sitekey.site_key, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM activation WHERE activation.site_key= sitekey.site_key) as key_count'); 
$this->db->from('sitekey'); 
$this->db->join('company', 'sitekey.org_id = company.id'); 
$query = $this->db->get(); 
$result = $query->result(); 

var_dump($result); 
return $result; 

}
```

Comment: no man, i dont need to use expiry data, i just want to show how many keys i have given to organization and how many have they used from it

Comment: Show structure "company"

Comment: added the company table , but i want to get the count of each key used in activation table,

Comment: So why you can't just GROUP BY site_key ?

Comment: SELECT company.org_name, sitekey.site_key, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM activation WHERE user_id = company.id) FROM sitekey
JOIN company ON sitekey.org_id = company.id

It must return
COMAPNY NAME, 4CAC-9CA7, 2 times
ANOTHER COMPANY, 4CAC-9CA7, 12 times

Comment: wil it do for all the keys in my database?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102580/discussion-between-aleksey-solomakha-and-rajan).

Comment: Hye i get when i print it in my view what can be the reson?Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$id

Answer (score 0):

Try this may be this will help you

```
public function get_key() {
               $result=$this->db->select('*')
                      ->from('activation')
                      ->group_by('yourfield')
                      ->get();
             $key_count= $query->num_rows();   
             return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I can't comment yet so I've to post an answer.

If you have a row per key in your activation table, you can just count everything

```
$this->db->from('activation')
->where('expiry_date <', date('U'))
->count_all_results();
```

> will return an int

If you want to group by a column, it's easy, juste add a group_by

```
$this->db->from('activation')
->group_by('site_key')
->where('expiry_date <', date('U'))
->count_all_results();
```

EDIT:

If you want to know of many licenses their is left, you can try

```
$this->db->from('activation a')
->select('COUNT(a.id) as used, s.licenses as max, max - used as left')
->group_by('a.site_key')
->join('sitekey s', 'a.sitekey = s.site_key')
->get()->results();
```

Comment: i dont need expiry data here. i just want to count the licenses i gave them and the licenses they have used from it

Comment: in sitekey table the licenses field defines how many times they can use this key

Comment: @Rajan I edited my answer, can you tell me if the last part works for you ?